# Android TV - Recommendation (Notification) will not auto-cancel

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

When creating a recommendation (or Notification) in Lollipop on Android TV, I cannot get it to Auto-cancel.

I am using the "NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle"  as recommended in the Android TV developer pages. The notification works as designed, triggering the PendingIntent as expected but does not auto-cancel and dissappear from recommendations bar. A second selection of the recommendation brings up a blank screen, so I guess the PendingIntent is null at that point. (ADB shows android.content.IntentSender$SendIntentException on 2nd invocation.)

Tested on Nexus Player and Android TV Emulator.

```
private void buildAndroidTVRecommendation(String name, PendingIntent pIntent,
        Context context2, Bundle extras) {

     NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context2.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Bitmap smallBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.air_share);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle(
            ( new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Air-Share - incoming share")
                    .setContentText("From: "+name)
                    .setContentInfo("Air-Share"))
                    .setGroup("Air-Share")
                    .setColor(0xFFFF2020)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_RECOMMENDATION)
                    .setLargeIcon(smallBitmap)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.air_share)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setExtras(extras)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)

                    )
            .build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(pendingCounter, notification);
    mNotificationManager = null;


}
```

Comment: When are you expecting it to auto-cancel? That recommendation is handled by the system when it comes to refreshing, switching position being dismissed/updated.

Comment: I was expecting similar auto-cancel behaviour as occurs on main-stream device android notifications. For example on a Jellybean tablet, when the user pulls down the notification bar and presses on a notification (with auto-cancel flag = true), the pendingIntent is activated and the notification disappears from the system.

Comment: As I said, it's probably not the case for Android TV. The recommendations are handled by the system, so it's not up to you to decide whether your content should be dismissed. Other apps (e.g., YouTube, DailyMotion, musixmatch, ..) are coherent with this behavior as well.

Comment: Perhaps you have a point but why does it generate a blank screen and an exception upon the second selection of the recommendation?

Comment: This sounds more like something's wrong on your side. I haven't experienced this issue when building my company's application (musixmatch).

Comment: From the Android API : setAutoCancel(boolean autoCancel)
Setting this flag will make it so the notification is automatically canceled when the user clicks it in the panel.

Comment: Your app does not run on Nexus Player? The crux of my argument is that autocancel for notifications is broken on Android TV builds.

Comment: Yes, it runs on Nexus Player, ADT-1 and Amazon Fire TV.

Comment: @Peter Are you actually able to get a notification to appear on Android TV? I haven't been able to. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757218/notification-wont-appear-on-android-tv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth I have created a work-around to get by this issue.

I created a new Activity whose sole purpose is to receive a Pending intent from the Recommendation.
I alter the original Pending Intent of the recommendation to invoke this new activity instead of my desired activity. (The desired activity is outside my app.) In the Extras, I bundle everything I need to know for my original desired intent as well as the notification ID.
When the new activity is launched (after user clicks on recommendation), I extract the ID and cancel the recommendation. I then extract the information for the desired intent, create the intent and finally finish the activity.

```
public class TVRecommendationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent in = (Intent) getIntent();
        String jsonString = in.getStringExtra("jsonString");
        String fileUri = in.getStringExtra("fileUri");

        int id  =in.getIntExtra("notificationID", -1);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (id >= 0 ) nm.cancel(id);

        JSONIntent newIntent = new JSONIntent(getApplicationContext());
        newIntent.setIncomingLocalFileURI(fileUri);
        Intent out = newIntent.buildIntentFromJSON(jsonString, fileUri);

        if (out != null) startActivity(out);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: FWIW I had the same question but was missing `setAutoCancel()`, adding caused my notifications to auto dismiss. (Nexus Player 5.1.1 LMY47V)